# topic is about sqlloader,table name is course and the filepath is mention

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

> error:C:\Users\ARAVIND>SQLLDR login/password
>
> control = D:\NEW\DATAA.CSV.txt

```
SQL*Loader: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Apr 15 22:02:44 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL*Loader-350: Syntax error at line 1.
Expecting keyword LOAD, found "CID".
CID,    CNAME
^
```

---

```
LOAD DATA 
INFILE 'D:\NEW\DATAA.CSV.txt'
INTO TABLE COURSE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(CID,CNAME)
```

Comment: what is the question

Comment: I don't follow what you are trying to do.  I'm assuming you're passing `control=d:\new\dataa.csv.txt` on the command line to `sqlldr`.  Is that really a control file?  It is named as if it was a data file.  I don't understand where `load data infile ...` is coming from.  Is that what is actually in `dataa.csv.txt`?  So it references itself??

Comment: Don't forget to change your SYSTEM password now that you've posted it here.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it properly, it works OK.

Input file (`dataa.csv.txt`) contents:

```
1,Little
2,Foot
```

Control file (`test36.ctl`) (location is, of course, different; I don't have your filesystem):

```
load data
infile 'm:\dataa.csv.txt'
truncate into table course
fields terminated by ','
(cid, cname)
```

Target table (`course`) description:

```
SQL> desc course
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------------------------
 CID                                                            NUMBER
 CNAME                                                          VARCHAR2(20)
```

Loading session & the result:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test36.ctl log=test36.log

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production on Pet Tra 16 09:12:37 2021

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 1
Commit point reached - logical record count 2

SQL> select * from course;

       CID CNAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Little
         2 Foot

SQL>
```